# Firebase Functions Typescript - Sending Emails with html templates

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, fs

I am trying to read html file with fs.readFile('../emailTemplates/template.html') from index.ts

my folders :

```
--src
  --index.ts
  --UsersFunctions
    --UserFunctions.ts
  --emailTemplates
    --template.html
```

from index.ts :

```
import * as UsersFunctions from './UsersFunctions/UsersFunctions';
export const newUserRegister = UsersFunctions.onCreateNewUser;
```

from UsersFunctions.ts

```
 export const onCreateNewUser = functions.firestore.document('users/allUsers/usersData/{userId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  fs.readFile("../emailTemplates/template.html", {encoding: 'utf-8'}, (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);

    }
    else {

    }
  });       
 }
```

i am getting an error from firebase functions :

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../emailTemplates/template.html'
at Error (native)
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'user_code/lib/emailTemplates/newUserRegisterHtmlTemplate.html'
```

I just want to send an email with html template 
maybe there is another way to do it ? 
i tired to search but found nothing regarding email templates with frirebase functions with typescript

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your path to the template doesn't match your project files organization.  I suggest that you only put TypeScript source code in `src` and put all other files you want to read and write under your `functions` folder at the same level as `src`.  So, you could organize your files like this:

```
/functions
    /src
        /index.ts
        /other source files
    /emailTemplates
        /template.html
```

Then, in index.ts, you could read template.html using the same path `../emailTemplates/template.html`.

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the entire, minimal function that demonstrates the problem (not just one line)?

Comment: The file of the code that's reading your template is actually deeper in the tree than just src.  Maybe you need another `..` in front of the relative path to reach up further in the tree.

Comment: also tried ../../emailTemplates no luck
just wanted to a read a file why its so hard ... btw when i used firebase functions with only javascript and without typescript every thing work just fine

Comment: @EranAbir I am having the same issue. Trying to use nunjucks to render the HTML template, but it is not working.

Comment: did you cp your templates into the lib/ folder? This makes it work for me

Comment: This approach doesn't work. Still getting `ENOENT` error

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `Path.join(__dirname, ...)` in order to read the file from disk. Firebase Functions does properly upload the additional files surrounding your code; however the internals of Functions causes the `process.CWD` info to mess up relative imports.

```js
const templatePath = Path.join(__dirname, 'emailTemplates', 'template.html');
fs.readFile(templatePath, 'utf-8', (err, template) => {
    // ...
});
```